# Как создать матрицу по заданному отношению (и создать само отношение) и как проверить рефлексивность и транзитивность?

Tags: python

На фото ниже приведен пример, который надо реализовать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите ваше решение и мпросите что у вас не получилось.
Оператор остаток от деления в Python выглядит так: %.
то есть например 4%2 = 0,  а   5%3=2 .
Думаю - теперь у вас все получится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

---

заданное множество:

```
In [83]: A = {1,2,3,4}
```

вспомогательная матрица:

```
In [84]: m = pd.DataFrame(np.array(list(A) * len(A)).reshape(len(A), -1),
                          columns=list(A), index=list(A))

In [85]: m
Out[85]:
   1  2  3  4
1  1  2  3  4
2  1  2  3  4
3  1  2  3  4
4  1  2  3  4
```

делим каждую строку вспомогательной матрицы на вектор `A` и проверяем остаток от деления на `1`:

```
In [86]: res = (m.div(list(A), axis=0) % 1 == 0).astype('int8')

In [87]: res
Out[87]:
   1  2  3  4
1  1  1  1  1
2  0  1  0  1
3  0  0  1  0
4  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

**«Как создать матрицу по заданному отношению (и создать само отношение)?»**

Отношение возможно задать прямо как множество пар, на Питоне как

```
rel = {(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 4)}
```

или каким-то *предикатом* (например вы использовали предикат `a делит b`), в случае которого возможно создать множество пар (после нужной подготовки) как *абстракцию множества* (set comprehension):

```
from itertools import product

set_a = (1, 2, 3, 4)
pred = lambda a, b: b % a == 0
rel = {(a, b) for (a, b) in product(set_a, repeat=2) if pred(a, b)}
```

После этого вы можете построить вашу таблицу, например, так:

```
table = [[1 if (i, j) in rel else 0 for j in set_a] for i in set_a]
```

и вывести её, например, командами

```
for row in table:
    print(row)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> [1, 1, 1, 1]
> [0, 1, 0, 1]
> [0, 0, 1, 0]
> [0, 0, 0, 1]
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

```
pred = lambda a, b: b % a == 0
```

то же самое, что и

```
def pred(a, b)
    return b % a == 0
```

т.е. функция, которая возвращает `True` или `False` в зависимости от условия, в этом случае от условия `a` делит `b` (математически `b ≡ 0 (mod a)` или остаток деления `b` на `a` есть `0`).

Функция `product()` из модуля `itertools` делает *декартово произведение:*

```
product(set_a, repeat=2)
```

эквивалентно

```
product(set_a, set_a)
```

Результат выражения

```
1 if (i, j) in rel else 0
```

если мы его обозначим как `result`, тот же самый, как при выполнении команд

```
if (i, j) in rel:
    result = 1
else:
    result = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

**«Как проверить рефлексивность и транзитивность?»**

Тест на *рефлексивность*:

```
def is_reflexive(rel, set_a):
    return {(a, a) for a in set_a} <= rel      #  <=  значит подмножество
```

Тест на *транзитивность*:

```
def is_transitive(rel):
    seconds_elements = {b for (a, b) in rel}
    for (a, b) in rel:
        for c in seconds_elements:
            if (b, c) in rel and (a, c) not in rel:
                return False
    return True
```

---

Тест этих функций:

```
def test(rel, set_a):
    print("Set:         ", set_a)
    print("Relation:    ", rel)
    print("Reflexivity: ", is_reflexive(rel, set_a))
    print("Transitivity:", is_transitive(rel))
    print(80 * "-")    set_a = (1, 2, 3, 4)


set_a = (1, 2, 3, 4)
rel = {(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 4)}
test(rel, set_a)

rel = {(1, 1), (1, 2)}
test(rel, set_a)

rel = {(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 4)}
test(rel, set_a)

rel = {(1, 2), (2, 3)}
test(rel, set_a)
```

Вывод:

> ```
> Set:          (1, 2, 3, 4)
> Relation:     {(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 3), (4, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1)}
> Reflexivity:  True
> Transitivity: True
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Set:          (1, 2, 3, 4)
> Relation:     {(1, 2), (1, 1)}
> Reflexivity:  False
> Transitivity: True
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Set:          (1, 2, 3, 4)
> Relation:     {(1, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1)}
> Reflexivity:  True
> Transitivity: False
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Set:          (1, 2, 3, 4)
> Relation:     {(1, 2), (2, 3)}
> Reflexivity:  False
> Transitivity: False
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```